# Interpretation of ANCOVA output

Tags: interaction, interpretation, predictor, ancova

I am struggling to interpret my ANCOVA output - I have looked at similar questions and can't figure it out.

I am looking to determine whether there are gender differences in the impact of a specified app feature on children's learning outcomes. (e.g. does the app feature work better for boys than girls?)

'female' is gender. My DV is EGRA improvement scores.
My covariate is an app feature - 'curriculum links' in the pictured example.

Am I right in thinking the main effect (female) being significant means that even when accounting for curriculum links, there is still a gender difference in the improvement score? If so, does this answer what I want to find out?

I am struggling to work out what the interaction means, whether this should be used to answer my question and why this may be insignificant when the main effect is significant.

Any clarity would be really helpful, thanks in advance!

[image]